# What does F.A.N.G.'s name stand for?

Tags: street-fighter-v

What does F.A.N.G.'s name stand for?

According to the [wiki](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/F.A.N.G) his nickname for mastering the art of poison attacks is "the Fang of the Nguuhao". So while it could be possible that F.A.N.G. is simply short for the first two letters of his nickname and the clanname, the game itself makes every letter abbreviated, which leads me to believe that F.A.N.G. must stand for something else.

Does F.A.N.G. stand for anything else?

Comment: I don't think Capcom has revealed that yet. We'll probably know more once the Story Mode releases in June.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F.A.N.G. stands for "Fantastic Asian Notorious Gang".

[Source](https://streetfighter.fandom.com/wiki/F.A.N.G#Trivia)